# Strict CSP rule in place - Is there an alternative mechanism to call localhost?

Tags: javascript, localhost, content-security-policy

I've service running my colleagues workstations locally (127.0.0.1), and I would like to call that service when they visit mysite.com, but I do have a strict CSP rule to enforce that no CORS is allowed.

CSP Error

```
Refused to connect to 'http://127.0.0.1/api/verify' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'
```

I understand I can relax my CSP rules to allow connect-src: 127.0.0.1, but I would like to check with the community on
whether there is an alternative mechanism to call the local service without update CSP rules.

Note: I have multiple sites that call the local service.

Comment: Why do you want an alternative mechanism in the first place? CSP is _the_ mechanism to configure access for such requests, and if browsers offered a way to circumvent CSP, there would be no point to CSP in the first place.

Comment: The `127.0.0.1` is not a public IP address, it always points to a user's local machine (routed to a `localhost`). That is, requests to `127.0.0.`1 are always sent to the user's local machine. So your service should be running on each colleagues PC.